# Rails: Linking from Subdomain to Main Domain and Back

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have an app with subdomains for various people that all share the same domain (i.e. `www.liz.domain.com`, `www.anthony.domain.com`, etc.).  I need to create links from one subdomain to the main domain and back, but can't figure out how to make it work.  My routes stand like this:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    constraints subdomain: 'liz' do
        scope module: 'liz', as: 'liz' do
            get 'home/index'
            root 'home#index'
            resources :inquiries
            get 'services/hire'
            get 'services/dev'
            get 'services/design'
            get 'services/branding'
            get 'services/portfolio'
        end
    end

    constraints subdomain: 'anthony' do
        scope module: 'anthony', as: 'anthony' do
            get 'home/index'
            root 'home#index'
        end
    end

    get 'home/index'
    root 'home#index'
end
```

And when I `rake routes` it turns out like this:

```
                Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                   Controller#Action
        liz_home_index GET    /home/index(.:format)         liz/home#index {:subdomain=>"liz"}
              liz_root GET    /                             liz/home#index {:subdomain=>"liz"}
         liz_inquiries GET    /inquiries(.:format)          liz/inquiries#index {:subdomain=>"liz"}
                       POST   /inquiries(.:format)          liz/inquiries#create {:subdomain=>"liz"}
       new_liz_inquiry GET    /inquiries/new(.:format)      liz/inquiries#new {:subdomain=>"liz"}
      edit_liz_inquiry GET    /inquiries/:id/edit(.:format) liz/inquiries#edit {:subdomain=>"liz"}
           liz_inquiry GET    /inquiries/:id(.:format)      liz/inquiries#show {:subdomain=>"liz"}
                       PATCH  /inquiries/:id(.:format)      liz/inquiries#update {:subdomain=>"liz"}
                       PUT    /inquiries/:id(.:format)      liz/inquiries#update {:subdomain=>"liz"}
                       DELETE /inquiries/:id(.:format)      liz/inquiries#destroy {:subdomain=>"liz"}
     liz_services_hire GET    /services/hire(.:format)      liz/services#hire {:subdomain=>"liz"}
      liz_services_dev GET    /services/dev(.:format)       liz/services#dev {:subdomain=>"liz"}
   liz_services_design GET    /services/design(.:format)    liz/services#design {:subdomain=>"liz"}
 liz_services_branding GET    /services/branding(.:format)  liz/services#branding {:subdomain=>"liz"}
liz_services_portfolio GET    /services/portfolio(.:format) liz/services#portfolio {:subdomain=>"liz"}
    anthony_home_index GET    /home/index(.:format)         anthony/home#index {:subdomain=>"anthony"}
          anthony_root GET    /                             anthony/home#index {:subdomain=>"anthony"}
            home_index GET    /home/index(.:format)         home#index
                  root GET    /                             home#index
```

I've tried using a `<%= link_to "Liz's Page", liz_root_path(subdomain: 'liz') %>` or `<%= link_to "Liz's Page", liz_root_path %>` from the main domain (without a subdomain), but neither links to the subdomain.

Similarly, I've tried `<%= link_to "Main Page", root_path %>` from a page inside a subdomain and it just links to the subdomain's home, not the site root.

Can anyone straighten me out on how to link back and forth between subdomains/main domains?

Answer (score 1):

I eventually changed these from `path` to `url` to solve the problem.

This way `<%= link_to "Liz's Page", liz_root_path(subdomain: 'liz')` %> became `<%= link_to "Liz's Page", liz_root_url(subdomain: 'liz') %>` and worked fine.

Comment: What about the back? When inside liz subdomain, how to link to domain?